# How to deal with margin right inside container with padding left

Tags: html, css

I have a common set up, a div with a padding with contents inside that has a `padding-right` property to seperate them.  When items are near the right hand edge then both the `padding-right` and overall padding (would be `padding-left`) from the parent div gets applied.  How can I overcome this issue?

```
#container {
    padding: 20px;
}

#container div {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: padding:0;!important on container div

Comment: Could you post an image of the desired result?

Comment: @DiederikEEn the important thing works on some elements but not all! Is there anything else I can do with it?

Comment: @Chris you could try this: `padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;` where 10px indicates the padding for the right side

Comment: @DiederikEEn you mean use padding instead of margin on the inner divs?

Comment: depends on what you realy want, margin moves up the amount of px you give, padding, stretches the div with the amount of pixels

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround for your scenario I would add :

```
#container:last-child {
    margin : 0;
}
```

Comment: the modern are - yes, all the ie8 and lower not :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to add margin-right. It takes by default since there is no float

```
#container div {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block; border:green solid 1px
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3xZ7n/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
#container div {
    margin: 0 0px 5px 5px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#container div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

:first-child is supported in IE8. last-child is not. So I have changed the margin to left

Answer (score 0):

As for browser support,

```
#container > div:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

seems to work effectively.

Comment: No idea what you mean... looked like one row in your example. Do you mean the divs are split in multiple rows? I think there is nothing you can do without some jquery. Otherwise please post hmtl